White grids appears when export GraphicsRow to PDF
I'm trying to export a GraphicsRow[{ListContourPlot[]}] to PDF.
(Added: for some reason I need to use the GraphicsRow rather than just ListContourPlot. And problem happens when I run this function. So I should find a workaround within the GraphicsRow logic.)
Code:
data = Table[Sin[x]  Sin[y], {x, 0, 2  Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2  Pi, 0.1}];

(*Generate the ListContourPlot without contour lines*)
plt = GraphicsRow[{listContourPlot = 
    ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, Background -> White, ImageSize -> 650]

Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.pdf", plt];

The image in the notebook is

While after output it becomes

There was a discussion for regionplot before:
Problem with exporting RegionPlot as PDF
But it has been years and some comment says this is fixed for regionplot. I'm using mathematical 14, and mine is not for regionplot. Any hint on solving this?

Looks like a problem with the resolution or rendering of the graphic in the pdf.  Can you try other types of graphic file formats?  Also, it seems like you can simplify your code listContourPlot = ListContourPlot[   data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 650] Not clear why you need GraphicsRow[]

Hi, I'm preparing to put several contourplots in a row with a common legend bar, that's why I'm testing the graphicsrow in this test code.

In preparing questions the best practice for this site - and generally for debugging - uses the minimal code example that produces the issue.  This enables those that want to provide answers to focus on the problem rather than wrestle with extraneous things.

Sticking with fixing the PDF, I added edges with the same color as the polygons:
Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.pdf"}], 
 plt /. {_EdgeForm, c_?ColorQ, rest__} :>
         {EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, c]], c, rest}
 ]
SystemOpen[%] (* to check result *)


There are other posts where the edge appear. Antialiasing seems to be a common culprit. The edges are drawn with some transparency, and the Background leaks through. However, I could not get a setting for Antialiasing to work.

Thank you! This seems to be the best option for me.

How about saving Rasterize[ ]'d image?
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.pdf", 
  Rasterize[listContourPlot, ImageResolution -> 600]];

The saved PDF image looks like


That's a good choice. But I found it gives a much larger file size if I want enough resolution after rasterizing compared with the methods given above. Thank you anyway.

Simplified code:
data = Table[Sin[x]   Sin[y], {x, 0, 2   Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2   Pi, 0.1}];

listContourPlot = ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 650, Mesh -> None]

Export["...Desktop/" <> "test.TIFF", listContourPlot];


TIFF file gives:

Looks like a limitation in pdf files.
Someone may know another workaround.
